# wpf textbox DirectionFlow

Tags: wpf, textbox

Here's the problem. I have a regular textbox that is used for number input to filter items in a list.

```
<TextBox x:Name="FilterTextBox" Text="{Binding FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Margin="5" />
```

Now the customer wants this code to be written right to left. I thought that this could be solved with FlowDirection however FlowDirection="RightToLeft" on the box does the same thing as the HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" or TextAlignment="Right" for that matter, meaning that if FlowDirection is "RightToLeft" and I type 3, then 4, then 5, the box will contain "345" aligned to the right, where I had expected it to be "543" aligned to the right, which is also what was requested.

Any idea of to get the desired effect, is FlowDirection supposted to be just a substitute for TextAlignment and I have misunderstood its purpose?

I suppose I could listen to key down event and insert the character at index 0, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it, all in xaml without code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="txtbxExample"  Width="100" Height="30" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs)
    txtbxExample.CaretIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Tested it out and typing 3 4 5 results in 543. This will probably be the simplest way to do it. Found no way to access the CaretIndex property from within Xaml using triggers, sorry.

Comment: Thanks but, that's pretty much what I already described that I could do in the last paragraph, I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it using only xaml, with no code-behind.

Comment: From what I can tell you can't. The CaretIndex property isn't accessible to triggers in XAML. You might be able to do it if you created your own custom textbox and changed the behavior of the control itself but from what I can tell that would also be outside the scope of what you want to do. I'll keep playing around with it and see if I can find a work-around that requires no code behind.

Comment: Yeah same here, and to be honest it's not really worth spending more time on the problem. Just curious if there is any pure xaml solution that already exists. Did something close to your suggestion, but basing it on e.Changes to account for editing in the middle of the text. "CaretIndex = e.Changes.ElementAt(0).Offset"

Comment: Nice, good call. And yeah I didn't end up finding anything that worked.